# Convert list of Fractions to floats in Python

Tags: python, floating-point, fractions

I have a list of fractions, such as:

```
data = ['24/221 ', '25/221 ', '24/221 ', '25/221 ', '25/221 ', '30/221 ', '31/221 ', '31/221 ', '31/221 ', '31/221 ', '30/221 ', '30/221 ', '33/221 ']
```

How would I go about converting these to floats, e.g.

```
data = ['0.10 ', '0.11 ', '0.10 ', '0.11 ', '0.13 ', '0.14 ', '0.14 ', '0.14 ', '0.14 ', '0.14 ', '0.13 ', '0.13 ', '0.15 ']
```

The `Fraction` module seems to only convert to `Fractions` (not from) and `float([x])` requires a string or integer.

Comment: Do you want to truncate or round after the second decimal?

Answer (score 15):

```
import fractions
data = [float(fractions.Fraction(x)) for x in data]
```

or to match your example exactly (data ends up with strings):

```
import fractions
data = [str(float(fractions.Fraction(x))) for x in data]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import fractions
data = [str(round(float(fractions.Fraction(x)), 2)) for x in data]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the fraction module is nice and tidy, but is quite heavyweight (slower) compared to simple string split or partition

This list comprehension creates the floats as the answer with the most votes does

```
[(n/d) for n,d in (map(float, i.split("/")) for i in data)]
```

If you want the two decimal place strings

```
["%.2f"%(n/d) for n,d in (map(float, i.split("/")) for i in data)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def split_divide(elem):
    (a,b) = [float(i) for i in elem.split('/')]
    return a/b

map(split_divide, ['1/2','2/3'])
```

[0.5, 0.66666666666666663]

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [ x.split('/') for x in data ]
data = [ float(x[0]) / float(x[1]) for x in data ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested list comprehensions will get you your answer without importing extra modules (fractions is only in Python 2.6+).

```
>>> ['%.2f' % (float(numerator)/float(denomator)) for numerator, denomator in [element.split('/') for element in data]]
['0.11', '0.11', '0.11', '0.11', '0.11', '0.14', '0.14', '0.14', '0.14', '0.14', '0.14', '0.14', '0.15']
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the previous answers seem to me to be overly complicated. The simplest way to do this, as well as doing numerous other conversions, is to use eval().

The following is one method

```
l=['1/2', '3/5', '7/8']
m=[]
for i in l
   j=eval(i)
   m.append(j)
```

The list comprehension version of the above is another method

```
m= [eval(i) for i in l]
```

each method results in m as

[0.5, 0.75, 0.875]